# imports error when I changed my project's root folder's name with GoLand

Tags: go, goland

My project's root folder is named as `simu`, and my import is like this: it works just fine.

```golang
import (
    "simu/pkg/timepoints"
    "simu/util"
)
```

However, I moved my project to another location, and the root path has change into `simulator`, all my imported module from the project itself reports errors, like this:
[image: err status]

The error message shown on the bottom status bar is `Cannot resolve directory 'simu'`.

My solution is to change the root folder back to `simu`, it works, but the question is that, if I have another project named as `simu` as well, what should I do? It's there a more flexible ways to keep my project root folder name as I want and the code is not affected?

Thanks for all your solution and comments ;-)

Comment: I'm sorry, but the picture is not uploaded, I'm currently fixing it..

Comment: are you using go modules ? Is Go modules integration enabled in you Goland ide settings ? Is "simu" is in your GOPATH like "GOPATH/src/simu" location ?

Comment: In `import (
    "simu/pkg/timepoints"
    "simu/util"
)` Your project base folder is simu but when you change the directory make sure you are using current directory name `import (
    "YourFolder/pkg/timepoints"
    "YourFolder/util"
)`

Comment: Try to use **Shift+F6** to rename the module name in your `go.mod` file. Then it is time to change your directory smoothly.